# DAX - Splitting on different delimiters in the same string

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

My cell data in PowerBI looks like this:

`25.10.2023_1181119 (0.0 St) [] 25.10.2023_1181118 (0.0 St)`

and I would like to return:

| Row | Article Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1181119 |
| 2 | 1181118 |

But I cannot work-out how to have a starting delimiter as "_" and an ending delimiter as " " or "(", and then reiterate it through the string. I've been trying with Custom Columns in PowerQuery, but with zero joy.

Help? Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Did any of these answers solve your issue? If so please toggle the checkmark next to it, and upvote

Answer (score 1):

This is an M answer, not DAX

You can split on spaces into rows, then split again on _

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"_"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Date", "Article Number"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Split Column by Delimiter1", each ([Article Number] <> null))
in  #"Filtered Rows"
```

[image]

Add column .. index column... afterwards if important, or right click remove date column

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have different start/end delimiters.

Paste this in a new blank query for an approach to this:

```js
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjLVMzTQMzIwMo43NLQwNDS0VNAw0DNQCC7RVIiOVcCQtoBLK8XGAgA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"_"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Drop", "Keep"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Drop"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Keep", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"_"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Keep.1", "Keep.2"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter2" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter1", "Keep.1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"1", "Drop"}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter2",{"Drop"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter3" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Keep.2", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"2", "Drop"}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter3",{"Drop"}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Columns2", {}, "Row", "Article Number")
in
    #"Unpivoted Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another Power Query method where we `transform` the initial column. Explanation of algorithm is in the code comments.
*You may want to set the data type for the `Article Number` column at the end*

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjLVMzTQMzIwMo43NLQwNDS0VNAw0DNQCC7RVIiOVcCQtoBLK8XGAgA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Extract Article" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {
        {"Column1", each 
            let

                //split by underscore and space 
                split = Splitter.SplitTextByAnyDelimiter({"_"," "})(_),

                //try to convert each item to a date, and return error status
                dates = List.Transform(split,(li)=>(try Date.From(li,"en-150"))[HasError]),

                //date positions in the list will be where [HasError] = false
                datePositions = List.PositionOf(dates,false, Occurrence.All)
            in 
                //Article number will be in the position just after the date position
                List.Accumulate(
                    datePositions,
                    {},(s,c)=> s & {split{c+1}}
                )
                }
    }),

    //Expand the list column
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Extract Article", "Column1"),

    //Add index column for your "Row" column
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "Row", 1, 1, Int64.Type),

    //Reorder and Rename the columns
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Index",{"Row", "Column1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Column1", "Article Number"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

***Source***
[image]

***Results***
[image]